# Why won't this compile?

Tags: java

Why doesn't this class compile?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Caesar
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        final boolean DEBUG = false;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Caesar Cypher");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
        String plainText = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter an offset: ");
        int offset = keyboard.nextInt();
        String cipherText = "";
        for(int i=0;i<plainText.length();i++)
        {
            int chVal = plainText.charAt(i);

            if (DEBUG) {int debugchVal = chVal;}

            chVal +=offset;

            if (DEBUG) {System.out.print(chVal + "\t");}

            while (chVal <32 || chVal > 127)
            {
                if (chVal < 32) chVal += 96;
                if (chVal > 127) chVal -= 96;

                if(DEBUG) {System.out.print(chVal+" ");}

            }

            if (DEBUG) {System.out.println();}

            char c = (char) chVal;
            cipherText = cipherText + c;

            if (DEBUG) {System.out.println(i + "\t" + debugchVal + "\t" + chVal + "\t" + c + "\t" + cipherText);}
        }
        System.out.println(cipherText);
    }
}
```

Comment: learn001@cis-lab pracset02 $ javac Caesar.java 
Caesar.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable debugchVal
location: class Caesar
                if (DEBUG) {System.out.println(i + "\t" + debugchVal + "\t" + chVal + "\t" + c + "\t" + cipherText);}
                                                          ^
1 error

Comment: sorry cant seem to get to grips with stack overflow formatting

Comment: Thankyou all for the quick reply. knew it was simple but just couldn't see it, you have opened my eyes.

Comment: Consider using an IDE such as Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ Idea when writing your code. They will immediately inform you about this kind of error.

Comment: @Ryan using spaces instead of tabs in your code makes it more readable accross all editors / viewers.

Comment: also, if i used single line if statements without {} blocking brackets would it still be out of scope?

Comment: Why won't this compile? is a really poor title for a question, and you really should add some context to go along with your code. If somebody had the same problem as you, it would be next to impossible to search for it.

Comment: if someone had the same problem they wouldn't be able to search for it, as it was difficult for me to come up with a descriptive title when i asked the question, as I had NO idea what the problem was.

if anyone can come up with a good title name your welcome to change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define variable `debugchVal` inside an `if` block:

```
if (DEBUG) {int debugchVal = chVal;}
```

So it exists only inside that block. Later when you refer to it again:

```
if (DEBUG) {System.out.println(i + "\t" + debugchVal + "\t" + chVal + "\t" + c + "\t" + cipherText);}
```

it is not in scope anymore, so the compiler dutifully emits an error.

Modify the first code part like this:

```
int debugchVal;
if (DEBUG) {debugchVal = chVal;}
```

Comment: Exactly.  google "Scope, Programming" to get some more information.

Comment: @Ryan just added my related comment to the main post :-)

Answer (score 5):

Declaration of variable `debugchVal` is inside the if block:

```
if (DEBUG) {int debugchVal = chVal;}
```

As a result it will not be available outside the if block. Move the declaration outside the if block as:

```
int debugchVal = /*some default value that makes sense if DEBUG is false */;
if (DEBUG) {debugchVal = chVal;}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are defining `debugchVal` inside a scope and you try to use it later.

You are doing:

```
if (DEBUG) {int debugchVal = chVal;}
```

and later:

```
if (DEBUG) {System.out.println(i + "\t" + debugchVal + "\t" + chVal + "\t" + c + "\t" + cipherText);}
```

but since `debugchVal` is defined between braces it's a local definition just to that scope. Try to move it out of the scope:

```
int debugchVal = -1;
if (DEBUG) { debugchVal = chVal; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You've declared `debugchVal` in a block like this:

```
if (DEBUG) {int debugchVal = chVal;}
```

That variable is only in scope for that block. It doesn't "exist" for the rest of the time.

You can do this:

```
int debugchVal = 0;
if (DEBUG) {
    debugchVal = chVal;
}
```

However, you might as well just always assign it (and give it a clearer name):

```
int initialChVal = chVal;
```

Having the assignment in the "non-debug" version won't hurt you.

You might also want to look at using something like java.util.Logging instead of this "DEBUG" pattern.

Answer (score 2):

debugchVal is defined INSIDE the if block. So its scope is only that.
Try to declare it outside (with a default value) and assign its correct value inside the if(DEBUG).

```
int debugChVal = 0;
if (DEBUG) {
   debugChVal = ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message, find the line number, find the according line (plus the previous line), look at the error message itself ("cannot find symbol") and look for an undefined variable. In 99% of all cases it is a simple typo that should be obvious if you use an IDE with good syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scope resolution problem. The debugchval variable is not available in the scope of the last if. You need to declare it outside the if conditions

Answer (score 1):

problem with scope on debugchVal:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Caesar
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final boolean DEBUG = false;
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Caesar Cypher");
      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
      String plainText = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter an offset: ");
      int offset = keyboard.nextInt();
      String cipherText = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++)
      {
         int chVal = plainText.charAt(i);
         int debugchVal = -1;

         if (DEBUG)
         {
            debugchVal = chVal;
         }

         chVal += offset;

         if (DEBUG)
         {
            System.out.print(chVal + "\t");
         }

         while (chVal < 32 || chVal > 127)
         {
            if (chVal < 32)
            {
               chVal += 96;
            }
            if (chVal > 127)
            {
               chVal -= 96;
            }

            if (DEBUG)
            {
               System.out.print(chVal + " ");
            }

         }

         if (DEBUG)
         {
            System.out.println();
         }

         char c = (char) chVal;
         cipherText = cipherText + c;

         if (DEBUG)
         {
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + debugchVal + "\t" + chVal + "\t" + c + "\t" + cipherText);
         }
      }
      System.out.println(cipherText);
   }
}
```